# Delete comment limit on Android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, rate-limiting

I know on the desktop site there is a limit of 5 seconds on adding new comments. This also applies to deleting comments.

Does the same logic apply on the Android app? I have seen a message for adding comments, but not for *deleting* them.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't appear to show me a message saying there is a limit, but only when deleting comments

Comment: So most likely it's an overlook on their side... enjoy this power while you can! :-)

Comment: support? or feature-request? or bug?

Comment: @Azik At the moment it's Support because I can't say this with 100% certainty. If I can get someone to confirm/repro, then it becomes a bug :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the limit on voting on comments is one second (probably because app can't send the requests faster). Note that on the site, the limit was removed at all.

Comment: Are you saying there is no longer a rate limit on the desktop version? And is this one second, or as fast as you can possibly post?

Comment: Yea, @RGra, the limit was completely removed on the desktop, can't find a post on it right now. And the minimal time between requests (for everything) in the app is 1 sec.